# Is it possible to query the stack space of a closure?

Tags: rust

```
fn test<T>(t: T) {
    println!("size of: {}", std::mem::size_of::<T>());
}
fn main() {
    let f = || {
        let i1: i32 = 0;
        let i2: i32 = 0;
        let i3: i32 = 0;
        i1 + i2 + i3
    };
    test(f) // prints "size of: 0"
}
```

A non move closure always seems to prints that the size is 0 probably because it is just inlined.

A move closure gets bigger with every variable that it captures but I wonder if it is possible to query the stack space that a closure requires?

Update:

I want to create something like a `Coroutine<F>`. I need to know the size of `F` for it to be executed. I currently allocate 1mb per coroutine which is way too much. So I was wondering if it would be possible to determine the actual size that I need to allocate.

Comment: FYI: there is [`mem::size_of_val()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of_val.html), so you don't need to write this `test()` function. It returns 0, too.

Comment: Since you use the term "stack space" instead of "stack size" in the title, I'm wondering: are you asking about the size required to store the closure, or the size required to execute it? I.e., is Lukas' answer correct, or are you wondering by how much the stack pointer is in-/decreased when calling the closure?

Comment: @Thierry I realize now that my phrasing was too confusing and I updated the question.

Comment: That doesn't really help me understand, tbh :/. So is my answer correct or are you talking about the stack space the closure needs to *run in*?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Yes the stack space that the closure needs to run, sorry for being so confusing.

Comment: I think it's pretty impossible. First of: you can't know the total amount of stack needed to run the closure. This is undecidable in the general case, e.g. `if turing_machine() { do_recursion(); }`. If you're in luck you can find out the size of the initial stack frame of the closure, but probably not in safe Rust. And I don't think that will help you. So yes, allocating a few MB is probably the solution you should go with... I think.

Answer (score 4):

*I misunderstood the question, so the following text does not really answer OP's question!*

---

**Yes**, you can measure the size of a closure. The sizes are just a bit confusing sometimes. Let's test all kinds of closures:

```
let constant = || 27;
let no_capture = |x: i32| 27 + x;

let a = vec![3];
let immut_capture = || a[0] + 27;
let immut_capture_arg = |x: i32| a[0] + x;

let mut b = vec![3];
let mut c = vec![3];
let mut_capture = || { b[0] += 27; b[0] };
let mut_capture_arg = |x: i32| { c[0] += x; c[0] };

let mut d = vec![3];
let mut e = vec![3];
let move_capture = move || { d[0] += 27; d.into_boxed_slice() };
let move_capture_arg = move |x: i32| { e[0] += x; e.into_boxed_slice() };
```

When I print their sizes with [`std::mem::size_of_val`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of_val.html) (which is roughly equivalent to your hand-written `test()` function), I get the following results:

```
constant -> 0
no_capture -> 0
immut_capture -> 8
immut_capture_arg -> 8
mut_capture -> 8
mut_capture_arg -> 8
move_capture -> 24
move_capture_arg -> 24
```

You can try it yourself with [this code on playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2c8ae6ab6ae375f1b2119d716771b625&version=stable&backtrace=0).

---

#### So whats up with those results?

A closure is a type that saves its environment – either by reference or by value. Mutable and immutable reference to sized data have the same size, namely `size_of::<usize>()`, usually 8. This explains the size of the closures that capture the outer variable by reference.

The move closures on the other hand, capture their environment by value, which means that they have to save the environment inside themselves. So it's no surprise that their sizes are equal to `size_of::<Vec<_>>()`.

What about the closures with size 0? Since they are not capturing any environment, they could be ordinary `fn`-functions, too. And I guess that Rust turns them into `fn`-functions. And in fact, if we try to print the size of an `fn`-item (not a function pointer!) like this:

```
fn foo(x: i32) -> i32 { x +  27 }
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of_val(&foo));
```

... we get 0!